# Can require() statement in commonjs be dynamic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

Is `require()` statement in commonjs module system static or dymanic?
Can `require()` be dynamic? Can anyone give examples for this?

is following code dynamic or static:

```
let c1="./c"
let c2=".js";
const f=require(c1+c2);

console.log(f);
```

I mean will c1+c2 resolved at compile time or run time?
I am totally confused with AI answers. Some time it is saying `require()` is dynamic sometimes it is saying it is static. Still Stackoverflow is best resource.

Comment: LLM "AI" systems are not computer programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dynamic, but a module is executed only once like in ESM. It's like a sync version of ESM's `import()`:

```
let count = 10;
while (count--) {

    const random = ['fs', 'fs2'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 1.9999)];
    console.log('require', random);

    try {
        const fs = require(random);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Each time this throws an error randomly:

```
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs
require fs
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
require fs2
Cannot find module 'fs2'
Require stack:
 - /bytex/change-color/test.js
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. can u elaborate "but a module is executed only once"?

Comment: JS code inside a module is executed only once

Comment: Is using dynamic require() a good practice? or can it cause any problems with bundlers like webpack?

Comment: @aLearner i would suggest to move to ESM (`import`). require is outdated, many new nodejs libraries don't support it. i'm using Vite so can't speak for webpack. But i'm pretty sure webpack supports 'import' too

Comment: @aLearner if you find my answer useful please accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up), thanks